# NPM not linking peer dependencies

Tags: angular, npm, npm-install

My package json is:

```
 "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "2.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/core": "2.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/http": "2.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/router": "^3.0.0-alpha.8",
    "autoprefixer": "^6.3.3",
   "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.6",
    "selenium-standalone": "^5.1.0",
    "style-loader": "^0.13.0",
    "stylelint": "^6.3.2",
    "stylelint-webpack-plugin": "^0.2.0",
    "to-string-loader": "^1.1.3",
    "ts-helpers": "^1.1.1",
    "tslint": "^3.3.0",
    "tslint-loader": "^2.1.0",
    "typescript": "^1.8.10",
    "typings": "^1.0.4",
    "webpack": "^1.13.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^1.14.1",
    "webpack-hot-middleware": "^2.9.1",
    "webpack-split-by-path": "0.1.0",
    "zone.js": "0.6.12"
  }
```

When I do npm install I get the following error:

```
+-- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY @angular/common@2.0.0-rc.4
+-- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY @angular/compiler@2.0.0-rc.4
+-- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY @angular/core@2.0.0-rc.4
+-- @angular/forms@0.2.0 
+-- @angular/http@2.0.0-rc.4 
+-- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY @angular/platform-browser@2.0.0-rc.4
+-- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY @angular/platform-browser-dynamic@2.0.0-rc.4
+-- @angular/router@3.0.0-rc.1 

npm WARN optional Skipping failed optional dependency /chokidar/fsevents:
npm WARN notsup Not compatible with your operating system or architecture: fsevents@1.0.14
npm WARN @angular/router@3.0.0-rc.1 requires a peer of @angular/core@^2.0.0-rc.5 but none was installed.
npm WARN @angular/router@3.0.0-rc.1 requires a peer of @angular/compiler@^2.0.0-rc.5 but none was installed.
npm WARN @angular/router@3.0.0-rc.1 requires a peer of @angular/common@^2.0.0-rc.5 but none was installed.
npm WARN @angular/router@3.0.0-rc.1 requires a peer of @angular/platform-browser@^2.0.0-rc.5 but none was installed.
npm WARN @angular/router@3.0.0-rc.1 requires a peer of @angular/platform-browser-dynamic@^2.0.0-rc.5 but none was installed.
```

If I go to the core library and do `npm list` I get the following:

```
node_modules/@angular/core$ npm list
@angular/core@2.0.0-rc.4
+-- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY rxjs@5.0.0-beta.6
`-- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY zone.js@^0.6.6

npm ERR! peer dep missing: rxjs@5.0.0-beta.6, required by @angular/core@2.0.0-rc.4
npm ERR! peer dep missing: zone.js@^0.6.6, required by @angular/core@2.0.0-rc.4
```

However rxjs@5.0.0-beta.6 and zone.js@^0.6.6 have already been installed as per the package.json. Why is npm not linking these libraries to the required libraries?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure all those are devDependencies, not dependencies which need to be deployed with the application (like angular for example)? If you have those angular modules in dependencies as well, then the peers rxjs and zonejs will need to be in dependencies.